# I don't understand why if two polynomials degrees do not exceed $n$ and they coincide at $n+1$ points then they are equal.

Tags: polynomials

> If polynomials P and Q has degrees not exceeding n and coincide at n+1
>   different points, then they are equal.
>
> $\text{Reference Below}$:

[image]

Comment: What can you say about the polynomial $P - Q$?

Comment: Are you having difficulty understanding the statement of the theorem itself, or the proof?

Comment: I am not understanding the corollary @Aky

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The corollary says that if $\deg P\le n$ and $\deg Q\le n$ and $P(x_i)=Q(x_i)$ for $i=1,2,3,\ldots,n, n+1$ then $P$ and $Q$ are the same polynomial.  The proof considers the polynomial $P-Q$, of which we can say $(P-Q)(x_i)=0$ for $i=1,2,3,\ldots,n,n+1$. We have $\deg(P-Q)\le n$ and $P-Q$ has more than $n$ zeros.  The theorem says that can't happen unless $P-Q$ is the zero polynomial, so $P$ must be the same as $Q$.

Answer (score 0):

In other words: a polynomial $P$ with degree $n>0$ is uniquely determined by $n+1$ values. If you have points $(a_0,b_0),\dots (a_n,b_n)$ with $a_i\neq a_j$ for $i\neq j$ and $P(a_i)=b_i$ for all $i=0,\dots n$, then you already know the polynomial $P$.

Thus: if polynomials $P$ and $Q$ with $\deg(P)=\deg(Q)=n$ coincide at $n+1$ different points $(a_0,b_0),\dots (a_n,b_n)$, then they must already be the same.